# d3js v5 + Topojson v3 Map with border rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I come back for a problem. I'm still learning d3js for 5 days and I have a problem about the border rendering.
Why I have that ?
[image: france country]

The problem occurs when I add region borders.

```
svgMap.append("path")
  .attr("class", "reg_contour")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(fr[0], fr[0].objects.reg_GEN_WGS84_UTF8, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
  .attr("d", path);
```

Here is my code : https://plnkr.co/edit/mD1PzxtedWGrZd5ave28?p=preview

Just for the record, the json file combines two layers (departments and regions) created with the same shp and compiled by QGIS for geojson output. After I convert this to topojson by mapshapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in your topojson - the two different feature types, departments and regions do not share the same coordinates along their common boundaries.

First, in this sort of situation it is desirable to check to make sure there is no layering issue (often other features are drawn ontop of others, hiding them or portions of them), we can do this by just showing the regional boundaries:

[image]

([plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oJPkCLTnyKKTIFdYIZwX?p=preview))

So the problem can't be layering, if we look at a particular feature in the topojson, say the department of Creuse:

```
{"arcs":[[-29,-28,-27,-26,202,-297,-296,205,-295,-410,419]],"type":"Polygon","properties":{"codgeo":"23","pop":120581,"libgeo":"Creuse","libgeo_m":"CREUSE","codreg":"75","libreg":"Nouvelle Aquitaine"}}
```

We see that the department is drawn using 11 arcs representing each portion of the boundary based on shared boundaries between multiple features so that shared boundaries are only represented once in the data.

If we zoom in on Creuse we can see those 11 arc segments shared between either other departments, regions, or with nothing at all:

[image]

*The thick portions of the boundary correspond to the thick white boundaries in the image in the question, I've only changed the styling and zoom from the original plunkr*

This looks problematic, the department should only have 6 arcs:

[image]

Why are there additional arcs? Because the boundaries of the departments are not aligned properly - the shared boundaries between departments do not always share the same arcs in your topojson. Chances are the departments might use a different scale than the regions, a different precision or projection, or were made somehow differently. This has resulted in minute nearly imperceptible differences that have resulted in boundaries that share coordinates in reality not sharing the same coordinates in the data, and thus the shared arcs are going unrecognized.

Since you are generating the mesh like this:

```
topojson.mesh(fr[0], fr[0].objects.reg_GEN_WGS84_UTF8, function(a, b) { return a !== b; })
```

Only shared boundaries are drawn, which explains the gaps.

We can rectify this a few ways, the easiest way would be to remove the regions altogether. The departments record which region they are in, we can check to see if a boundary should be drawn if the departments on each side of that boundary are in different regions:

```
.datum(topojson.mesh(fr[0], fr[0].objects.dep_GEN_WGS84_UTF8, function(a, b) { return a.properties.libreg !== b.properties.libreg; }))
```

Which gives us:

[image]

([plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8QgBjoMPGMffOiEPgQxW?p=preview))

Alternatively, we can re-habilitate the regional boundaries by importing them into a GIS platform such as ArcGIS and repairing the geometry. We could also import the departments and make a new layer based on region properties in a dissolve. Using the repair geometry tool in Arc, I get a nice boundary (when shown with the same code as the first image here):

[image]

There are other methods, such as including a tolerance in aligning arcs, but these might be more difficult than the above.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ! 
Is there a way of how to make the cities or regions have equal size in the area ?